# How to transfer youtube video from one account to the other without reuploading on my server?

Tags: youtube, youtube-api

I want to transfer some videos from youtube(I've videos ids) to my own youtube account.
How to do it without downloading video to my server and uploading to my account?(This is not good solution for me because the traffic on my hosting is limited and it's so long process(download+upload))

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just create a playlist in your channel and add those videos into your playlist. They will still be hosted in their original channel's upload playlist as well though.

Comment: Thanks for answer. But what's happened with video in my playlist when orginal video has been deleted?

Comment: It would be deleted as well.

Comment: But I wanna save this video because it was uploaded on my own site/ Is it really ?